# selenium click() skipping

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have been doing some work with selenium lately and I am having an issue with the click() function.

Given the following HTML code:

```
    <div id="sendreply">
      <input type="submit" class="button norm-green" value=
      "Send Message name="sendmessage"> == $0
    </div>
```

I have been trying to click on the "Send Message" button however click() just passes over the action and the program proceeds to downstream operation.

I have tried finding the element by both name and xpath:

```
    time.sleep(2)
    option='by_name'
    if option == 'by_name':
        driver.find_element_by_name('sendmessage').click()
    else:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='sendreply']").click()
```

I get no error code whatsoever.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please note that I made an error when I copied the HTML. The actual HTML contains a double prime: "Send Message"

Answer (score 0):

If you've tried all but nothing get success, try using `execute_script()` as an alternate solution to perform click and get rid from this issue as below :-

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", driver.find_element_by_name('sendmessage'))
```

**Warning**:- The `JavaScript` injection `HTMLElement#click()` shouldn't be used in a testing context. It defeats the purpose of the test. First because it doesn't generate all the events like a real click `(focus, blur, mousedown, mouseup...)` and second because it doesn't guarantee that a real user can interact with the element. But you can use it as an alternate solution to get rid from this issue.